# Firebase Storage - Dynamically create an object from adding a file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Imagine - there is a list view. Each list item is an audio file (when I press it - it plays a sound). Currently, the list is empty. I was wondering - is it possible to when I add an audio file from Firebase console using my PC it instantly creates a list item containing download link and etc visible on my phone? Or do I need to have a firebase database node which has a download link? If that's the way - how do I automatically assign the download URL to the database node?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, the answer to the first question is yes. You can add the download URL of an uploaded file after it is has successfully been uploaded to storage, however, I have not tried this using the console. The only thing I can think of  is copying the URL of the file from Firebase storage and adding it as a child to a node in the database (to the node of interest). skeleton code of my suggestion is as follows:

```
   var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref().child('audiofiles').put(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

  }, function (error) {

      switch (error.code) {
        case 'storage/unauthorized':
            alert("Storage Unauthorised: " );
          break;

        case 'storage/canceled':
          alert("Storage Canceled: " );
          break;

        case 'storage/unknown':
           alert("Storage unknown: " );
          break;
      }

  }, function complete () 

  {
     //obtain the URL for the newly uploaded file
     var dwnURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

     //implement logic to save dwnURL to Firebase database below
```

}

Look at [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files/%22Firebase%20Documentation%22) for more information.

Comment: The question states that the file upload happens through the console, not through the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a file through the console to your storage bucket, then you will also have the make the manual change to a database node to make that new file "visible" to your app.  This is because there is currently no API to list all the files in a bucket from a mobile app.

If you want to manually create that node in the database to point to your file in storage, that's doable.  The download URL for every file is visible in the console, so you can copy that and paste it into the appropriate location in your database so that it can be discovered by your app.  There is currently no way to do this mapping automatically, unless you want the upload to go through a server you control that performs this work.

Comment: Thanks. That is what was my first thought I just was wondering if there is another way to do it

Comment: Also to add - there is no way to generate automatic key so I need to do that by myself, right?

Comment: A key for what, the name of the file in storage?  You'd have to come up with that yourself (UUID) or use a Firebase push id.

Comment: I meant Push ID